# How to fix prestashop 1.5.6 mail?

Tags: php, email, smtp, prestashop

PHP version: 5.4.16
Prestashop version: 1.5.6.2
Mail alerts module version: 2.8

Neither the contact form or order mail is working. But the test mail is working.

The contact form is working in that way that when you hit the send button i get forwarded to the confirmation page, but the mail doesn't sends.

It seems not to be a firewall problem, since other sites hosted at the same web server are able to send mails using the same SMTP server and the same login credentials.

From the mail server log file:

connect from xxx
lost connection after connect from xxx
disconnect from xxx

We can't see any error messages.